# t3api extension is returning a 404 page not found TYPO3

Tags: php, api, typo3

I am trying to add custom API-s endpoints to my TYPO3 CMS.
Here is the model for my Projects.

```
namespace Geraldib\PortfolioSite\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;
use SourceBroker\T3api\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "path"="/projects",
 *          },
 *     },
 * )
 */
class Project extends AbstractEntity
{
```

I have also included this code in my config.yaml

```
imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:t3api/Configuration/Routing/config.yaml" }
```

Here is the Response it returns.

[image]

I was expecting a array of all projects to be returned. Should I implement this route in my controller if so because I don't see anything in the docs.

The code Structure
[image]

**TYPO3 version 11.5**
Client side url: *http://localhost/Typo3/geraldib-site/public/*

Answer (score 0):

The Urls in your screenshot does not correspond to anything common to a TYPO3 installation. (Which TYPO3 version do you use?)

A typical TYPO3 installation would consist on this folder structure:

starting with a installation root which would be something like:
`/srv/www/htdocs/projectname`.
There you have multiple folders with `public/` as the folder which represents the web root:
`/srv/www/htdocs/projectname/public` (`https://mydomain/`)

Up to TYPO3 11 in the web root you have a folder `typo3conf/` with a subfolder `ext/` where all extensions are stored:
`/srv/www/htdocs/projectname/public/typo3conf/ext/` or `https://mydomain/typo3conf/ext/`

So files of the extension `t3api` (which could be addresses inside of TYPO3 as `ext:t3api/...`) would be accessible as `/srv/www/htdocs/projectname/public/typo3conf/ext/t3api/...` on server side
or `https://mydomain/typo3conf/ext/t3api/...` on client side.

Your URLS look like a mix of local and client paths, which probably will fail.

Comment: It is a composer TYPO3 project. The link to the homepage is http://localhost/Typo3/geraldib-site/public/

Comment: It is hosted in xampp local server. I have no idea why the requested url is http://localhost/Typo3/geraldib-site/public/Typo3/geraldib-site/public/_api/projects
seems like "Typo3/geraldib-site/public" is repeated twice.

Comment: Version is 11.5 TYPO3

Comment: I still think that you have a wrong configuration about the web path of your installation. If you have TYPO3 in a subfolder it is a little bit complicated to get all paths correct.

Comment: I assume that your screenshot shows the instance root and that the folder `local_packages/portfolio_site` is an extension source which gets linked or copied to `public/typo3conf/ext/portfolio_site` (open `public/typo3conf/ext/`)

Comment: local_packages/portfolio_site is my site package and yes I just checked and it gets copied to the url public/typo3conf/ext/portfolio_site                                                 Will it fix my problem if TYPO3 project is inserted directly in htdocs and not inside a folder called typo3? I tend to group my projects by the cms or framework that is why this project is inside a typo3 directory

Comment: as the backend of TYPO3 is accessed by adding `/typo3/` to the webroot path it is misleading if you have it (also) in another part of the path. if you have an own domain for the TYPO instance you probably will have less difficulties to configure TYPO3 site path. That does not mean you must store it in another folder of the server, but you should configure an own domain (subdomain) to exact that folder (.../public)